# How can i be stuck with such a compatibility mismatch ? python-dateutil

Tags: python, heroku, python-dateutil

i'm developing a django app including boto 3; botocore (for aws s3 connections), pandas (automatically included with django i suppose) and heroku (amongst others)
Here is my problem : 
 - botocore 1.12.250 has requirement python-dateutil<3.0.0
 - pandas 0.24.2 has requirement python-dateutil>=2.5.0
 - heroku 0.24.2 has requirement python-dateutil>==1.5

All are the latest upgraded versions.
As I'm a beginner, I can't believe nobody use at the same time heroku and boto 3, or heroku and pandas - they are popular pips !
how can somebody use the heroku pip and pandas or boto at the same time ?

Because of that i can't lock my environement, and can't push to heroku...

Here is my requirements.txt :

```
astroid==2.2.5
boto3==1.9.250
botocore==1.12.250
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.6
django-autoslug==1.9.6
django-ckeditor==5.7.1
django-csvimport==2.12
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-isbn-field==0.5.2
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-storages==1.7.2
docutils==0.15.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
heroku==0.1.4
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.21
jmespath==0.9.4
json-table-schema==0.2.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
lxml==4.3.4
mccabe==0.6.1
messytables==0.15.2
numpy==1.16.4
pandas==0.24.2
Pillow==6.0.0
pipenv==2018.11.26
psycopg2==2.8.3
pylint==2.3.1
python-dateutil==1.5
python-magic==0.4.15
python-magic-bin==0.4.14
python-stdnum==1.11
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.5
sqlparse==0.3.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
Unidecode==1.1.1
urllib3==1.25.3
virtualenv==16.6.1
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
webencodings==0.5.1
wrapt==1.11.2
xlrd==1.2.0
```

In this case, i forced python-dateutil to 1.5, then got this error when locking pipenv :

```
ERROR: botocore 1.12.250 has requirement python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; 
python_version >= "2.7", but you'll have python-dateutil 1.5 which is 
incompatible.
ERROR: pandas 0.24.2 has requirement python-dateutil>=2.5.0, but you'll 
have python-dateutil 1.5 which is incompatible.
```

When i modify to the most recent version of python-date-util, i got the 
reverse error when locking pipenv :

```
ERROR: heroku 0.1.4 has requirement python-dateutil==1.5 , but you'll 
have python-dateutil 2.8 which is incompatible.
```

i would like to avoid the mismatch with the desired and required packages.
Thanks for youur help, I've been stuck with this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

heroku 0.1.4 is deprecated as stated at the top of this page:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py

Try using the community-supported heroku3 package as per [this suggestion](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5494#issuecomment-397122243) which has more modern dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I saw this answer but it's not developed by the heroku team and all the commands are different. There's not a lot of documentation about this package and i'm not sure if it's reliable...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the pip package is deprecated as mentioned above. You should just remove it from your requirements.txt, since you've likely installed it as a system package via:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli